# Action Cable for notification in each namespace in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

My project has three namespaces: `Trainee`, `Trainer`, and `Manager`. I use three templates for each namespace. I use action cable for notification (which uses websocket) in the project. Each namespace has different notification. How can I create a namespace for a channel?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't create a namespace for a channel, you would just create separate streams to subscribe to, like you would for chat rooms.

You could pass in a "namespace" parameter when creating the subscription, like so:

```
App.cable.subscriptions.create({
  channel: 'NotificationChannel', namespace: <%= namespace %>
}, {}
```

then subscribe to a different streams based on the namespace param:

```
class NotificationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from notification_stream
  end

  def receive(data)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast notification_stream, data.fetch('message')
  end

  private

  def notification_stream
    "#{params['namespace']}_stream"
  end

end
```